# I'm trying to make a six color led light

Tags: power-supply, voltage, led, resistors, batteries

how many 5mm miniature led lights can be powered by two 20 mm lithium coin cell batteries? And how many and what kind of resistors does it need to work?

Comment: Depends on how bright you want them.

Comment: Maybe you should link some datasheet...

Comment: coin cells have high ESR suitable for 10mA to 20mA  use CR2 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you can drive hundreds of LEDs. Of course, the current for each will be so small that the LEDs will effectively turned off, but you didn't specify either brightness or current levels. Also, you did not specify how long you want the batteries to last.

So let's start with the batteries. CR2032 (which is what I assume you're talking about, but it's just one more thing you forgot to mention) have a nominal voltage of 3 volts (at very low currents) and a capacity of 225 mAh. That is, they'll put out 1 mA for about 225 hours before the cell voltage drops below 2 volts. However, the effective capacity drops with increasing current. I suggest you read [this article for some representative numbers](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4429960/How-much-energy-can-you-really-get-from-a-coin-cell-). And let's use the data from the article as a starting point.

Assume you want to be able to see the LEDs well, and figure on 5 mA per LED. This conveniently matches the 30 mA curve  in the article. Note that, when fresh, a 2032 will only put out 2.5 volts at this current, so the total battery voltage to start will be about 5 volts.

Different color LEDs will have different voltage drops at the same current, but let's work with 2 volts. Reds are typically a bit less, blues a bit more. Then the resistor must drop 3 volts when fresh, and let's put the cutoff point at half that current, or a resistor drop of about 1.5 volts, for a battery cutoff voltage of 3.5 volts, or 1.75 volts per cell. Looking at the curve in the article, you'll get about 100 mAh before the battery voltage drops too low. At an average current of about 22 mA (30 + 15 / 2) you'll get something like 4 hours out of your battery.

And the dropping resistor for each LED is simply 3/.005, or 600 ohms. This will be a bit bigger for red LEDs and a bit smaller for blue.

Comment: you neglected ESR of LED and Coin cell (15 and 10 Ohms approx respectively

Comment: @TonyStewart - ESR of cell is taken into account in link (and roughly accounts for fresh voltage of 2.5 volts at 30 mA). ESR of LED at 10 ohms is insignificant compared to 600 ohms, especially considering the acknowledged imprecision of the LED forward voltage.

Answer (score 0):

> how many 5mm miniature led lights can be powered by two 20 mm lithium coin cell batteries?

First thing you need to do is figure out the maximum current total the LEDs can handle.

> And how many and what kind of resistors does it need to work?

This is where ohms law helps.

Determine the voltage you're giving to the circuit. I'm going to assume each lithium battery you're using is 3 volts and brand new. That gives you 6 volts total.

Next, take that maximum current rating you discovered earlier. I'm going to assume here 50 milliamps.

With ohms law, take voltage, and divide it by current to get resistor value. So in my example, 6 volts divided by 0.050 amps (which is 50 milliamps converted to amps) equals 120 ohms.

Therefore, the minimum resistor value you need for maximum LED brightness (without exploding the insides of the LED) from a brand new set of batteries is 120 ohms.

To determine the wattage (which is also another specification for a resistor), use ohms law again. Take the current value and multiply it by voltage. In my example, 6 volts multiplied by 0.050 amps equals 0.3 watts. This means the resistor needed for this circuit must be rated for 1/2 watt since that is the next standard size up from 0.3 watts.

Now based on the title of your post, you can actually create seven colors with only one LED. Look for an RGB LED and light two lights at once to create more colors. an RGB LED will be cheaper and require less labour to construct the circuit than six individual coloured LEDs.

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8N3Cg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since Blue/Green/White LEDs in 5mm are 3.1 for B/W and 3.2 for Green  YOu can run about 10~15mA per LED directly in parallel with each 3.0V Lithium cell. Of course battery life depends on how many you put in parallel on each battery based on mAh of cell  . Lithium cells are 3.00V  since 5mm LEDs have an ESR of 15~20 Ohms above 2.8V 20mA tends to yield 300~400mV above 2.8V so 3.0V will be less than 20mA and have no risk of thermal runaway without Rs.

This is the most efficient use of LEDS with Lithium primary cells.

20mm Li cells are 210mAh so 1 LED per cell will last 10h ~15h max.

A better solution uses more economical CR2 Lithium 3V and put all LEDs in parallel [image]  but don't put Lithium batteries in parallel. series is OK  26$cdn/6pack